# Replace inner html with value of html time a value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with an HTML table structure that contains values of text and integer.  My goal is to identify which cells contain integer values and replace them with their value times -1.  For instance:

> This Year | 5 | 4 | -12
>
> Last Year | 2 | 2 | 20

Would be updated to:

> This Year | -5 | -4 | 12
>
> Last Year | -2 | -2 | -20

Ideally, I would accomplish this with one line of JavaScript/jQuery.  The line I am working with is:

```
$(".value-cell").filter(function( index ) {return $.isNumeric($(this).text());}).text(parseFloat($(this).text())*-1);
```

However, this line just fills the cells with `NaN`.  I have tried a few variations of this but have not been able to accomplish what I am looking for.

**UPDATE:**

I should note, the filtration is working as expected and hitting the cells I want it to. I believe the problem lies with accessing `$(this)` in the text assignment, however, I am unsure of how else to access the text of the HTML element to multiply by -1.

Comment: Instead of returning directly to the html element, try debugging your isNumeric code and pass random values. You could do this in firefox or chrome console of that page

Comment: I should note, the filtration is working as expected and hitting the cells I want it to.  I believe the problem lies with accessing $(this) in the text assignment, however, I am unsure of how else to access the text of the html element to multiply by -1

Comment: try this:$(".value-cell").filter(function( index ) { return $(this).text(parseFloat($(this).text())*-1);});

Answer (score 2):

Pass a function to `.text()` to have it operate on each element.

```js
$(".value-cell").filter(function(index) {
  return $.isNumeric($(this).text());
}).text(function(i, txt) {
  return parseFloat(txt) * -1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=value-cell>abc</div>
<div class=value-cell>123</div>
```

And if you don't need the filtered set after this, you can get rid of the `.filter()` call and make the new value conditional.

```js
$(".value-cell").text(function(i, txt) {
  return $.isNumeric(txt) ? parseFloat(txt) * -1 : txt;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=value-cell>abc</div>
<div class=value-cell>123</div>
```

And of course, a modern syntax solution with no jQuery dependency could look like this:

```js
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll(".value-cell")) {
  const t = el.textContent;
  el.textContent = !t || isNaN(t) ? t : +t;
}
```

```html
<div class=value-cell>abc</div>
<div class=value-cell>123</div>
```

Comment: This did it! Thanks!  Your second solution is exactly what I am looking for.  Does passing a function to any method on a DOM element always work as first parameter index and second parameter innerHTML?